# Rerunning my main method after my boxPrint method

Tags: java, loops, methods

Hi I am trying to get this to reloop through my code but it seems to just exit after it prints the box:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoxPrint1 {   

    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);// create scanner object called input  
        // delcare variables

        int column;   
        int row;     

        System.out.printf("%nThis program prints a box");       // prompt user for input
        System.out.printf("%n Please enter # of columns (< 1 to exit):");
        column = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("%n Please enter # of rows (< 1 to exit):");
        row = input.nextInt();
        boxPrint(column, row);

        while(column > 0 && row > 0);  
        {    // calls boxPrint method and passes two arguments  
            // prompt user for input
            System.out.printf("%n Please enter # of columns (< 1 to exit):");
            column = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%n Please enter # of rows (< 1 to exit):");
            row = input.nextInt();
        }   
    }// end main


    public static void boxPrint(int column, int row)
    {
        //insert nested for loops below
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < column; j++) 
            {
                    // prints * j times in a row
                System.out.printf("*");
            }
        System.out.println();
        } // end boxPrint method
    }   
    // end class BoxPrint1
}
```

that is my code and usually i get the output of  (what it should output)

---

---

---

---

etc like so but it does not reloop to my main method and ask for input again?

Comment: Use while(true) at the begining of main method and close it just before // end main.

Answer (score 0):

Change the main method to look like the following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);// create scanner object called input
    // delcare variables

    int column;
    int row;

    System.out.printf("%nThis program prints a box");       // prompt user for input
    do {
        System.out.printf("%n Please enter # of columns (< 1 to exit):");
        column = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("%n Please enter # of rows (< 1 to exit):");
        row = input.nextInt();
        boxPrint(column, row);
    } while (column > 0 && row > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you've put up a semicolon after the while loop check.
It doesn't go inside the while loop at all to prompt you to enter input again.